# error when I instantiate Twilio.Call function - Undefined 'info'

Tags: twilio, twilio-sdk

I am trying to make an outbound call with Twilio Voice SDK in HTML.

I am getting the following error when I instantiate **Twilio.Call** function

```
const device = new Device(token);
 params = {
        params: {
            To: phone
        }
    };
const call = device.connect(params);
var callTemp = new Twilio.Call(call);
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'info')
at Object.Call (twilio.min.js:1:26960)
at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4:4994), <anonymous>:501:20)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5:14129)
at v.handle (jquery.min.js:5:10866)
```

What is the correct way to instantiate the **Twilio.Call**?

Answer (score 1):

You should not instantiate a `Twilio.Call` object yourself. The method [`device.connect`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceconnectconnectoptions) returns a promise that resolves to a `Twilio.Call` object.

```js
const device = new Device(token);
device.connect().then(call => {
  // Now you have the Twilio.Call object
})
```

Or with async/await:

```js
const device = new Device(token);
const call = await device.connect();
```

Comment: How to use "const call = await device.connect();" this call instance to invoice sendDigit() function? The example you posted is a nodeJS example. I am using HTML and JS.

Comment: My example is JS, not Node. You don’t have to use await if you don’t want to though, you can use the promise like in the first example.